# Testing for uncommitted changes in mercurial

Tags: mercurial

What's the best way to check in script if there're uncommitted changes in mercurial's working tree.

(the way I would with `git diff --quiet` in git)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In mercurial 1.4 and later you can use the summary command, which gives output like this when changes exist:

```
$ hg summary
parent: 0:ad218537bdef tip
 commited
branch: default
commit: 1 modified
update: (current)
```

and this post-commit:

```
$ hg summary
parent: 1:ef93d692f646 tip
 sfsdf
branch: default
commit: (clean)
update: (current)
```

Alternately, you could install the [prompt extension](http://stevelosh.com/projects/hg-prompt/) and do something like this:

```
$ hg prompt '{status}'
```

which will output a `!` or `?` or nothing as appropriate.

Both of those, of course, are just alternate text outputs.  I couldn't find anything that used the exit code directly, but since $? checks the last command in a pipe you could do?

```
hg summary | grep -q 'commit: (clean)'
```

which will set $? non-zero if any changes are uncommitted:

```
$ hg summary | grep -q 'commit: (clean)' ; echo $?
0
$ echo more >> that 
$ hg summary | grep -q 'commit: (clean)' ; echo $?
1
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I ended up with (in zsh) `[[ "nothing changed" = ``hg ci -m tick`` ]] || hg push`. And I don't like it because in some future version of mercurial the exact wording could change (that also applies to your hg summary solution). Yes, `hg prompt '{status}'` should work fine, except that I would prefer using core hg functionality because the script will be running on an external hosting so my custom extension (thus updated manually) could one day become incompartible with new hg (autoupdated) version.

Comment: Your concerns about the string changes make sense, but short of running on a different locale I don't think it will be as issue.  Matt Mackal, mercurial author, considers the text output part of the API and no change is allowed to alter it if any other option is available.  You'll not see that format change.

Comment: Hmm. Good to know. Not that I would consider this a great design decision ;) but it is somewhat comforting to bear this in mind.

Comment: Yeah, part of it was a licensing thing.  Mercurial was a GPL2 hold out, so it couldn't legally be in-process with non-GPL2 software, including GPL3 stuff.  Thus, a lot of interaction had to happen via stdin/stdout, and recognizing that MPM did a great job of watching for needless interface changes.

Comment: If you want to allow untracked files `hg summary | grep -Pq 'commit: (?:\d+ unknown )?\(clean\)'; echo $?`

Answer (score 6):

You can also run `hg id`. If the hash ends with a `+` it indicates the working copy has changes. This should even work with old versions of hg.

It sounds like you're already using zsh; well, a couple days ago I helped to update the Mercurial support for the built-in [VCS_INFO](http://kriener.org/articles/2009/06/04/zsh-prompt-magic) for putting VCS info in your prompt. Slated for the next release is support for showing changes to the working directory (among other things). If you don't want to wait you can [grab the necessary files from CVS](http://zsh.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/zsh/zsh/Functions/VCS_Info/).

At the moment my prompt includes this (using only built-in zsh functionality):

```
   (hg)[1801+ branchname somemq.patch, anycurrentbookmarks]
```

Comment: This does not work if you added a new file which was not added to the repository

Answer (score 5):

I use:

```
hg status -m -a -r -d -u
```

If no changes with tracked files, then the command output is an empty string.

Answer (score 3):

I use this bash-snippet for some time now:

```
if [[ $(hg status 2>/dev/null) ]]
then
    # do something
fi
```

Comment: This is triggered with untracked files present as well, which might not be what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Both `id` and `summary` are slower than `status`, so this is the fastest way I currently know, ignoring untracked files:

```bash
[[ -z `hg status | grep -v '^?'` ]] && echo no-changes || echo has-changes
```

Comment: `-mard` will skip untracked files. No need for the `grep -v`

Answer (score 0):

There should be something more elegant than simply

```
[ `hg st |wc -l` -eq 0 ] && echo hi
```